# MYSQL: How to Select Customers That Bought One Product But Not Another

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am working on a database and I would like to get the list of all the customers that bought a product with a name containing citroen but none with a name containing guzzi.

The structure of the database is the following:

[image: Database]

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT customerName, productName
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN orders o
USING (customerNumber)
INNER JOIN orderdetails od
USING (orderNumber)
INNER JOIN products p
USING (productCode)
WHERE productName LIKE '%citroen%'
AND productName NOT IN (
SELECT productCode
FROM products
WHERE productName LIKE '%guzzi%'
);
```

but it selects also the one who bought guzzi.

Any clue?

Comment: Use conditional aggregation in HAVING.

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry, I am just a beginner

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please share  your attempts to resolve the problem, along with sample data and the expected result according to that sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last condition, you're comparing productName with productCode, so I suppose the NOT IN will always return TRUE.

````sql
SELECT customerName, productName
FROM customers c
    INNER JOIN orders o
        USING (customerNumber)
    INNER JOIN orderdetails od
        USING (orderNumber)
    INNER JOIN products p
        USING (productCode)
WHERE productName LIKE '%citroen%'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 'x'
    FROM orders o2
        INNER JOIN orderdetails od2
            USING (orderNumber)
        INNER JOIN products p2
            USING (productCode)
    WHERE o2.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
    AND p2.productName LIKE '%guzzi%'
)
AND productName NOT LIKE '%guzzi%'
;```
````

Comment: Just to add more info: even if you'd have compared the correct fields in the NOT IN, the query wuold have resulted in "show me all the rows with productName like 'citroen' _and not like 'guzzi'_  ...but if it's like 'citroen' it will never be like 'guzzi'. Furthermore, you don't have just to exclude the orders with products like 'guzzi', but you need to know customers that DOESN'T have ordered 'guzzi' products. There is why you need the NOT EXISTS instead of the NOT IN.

Comment: @Ma3x `but if it's like 'citroen' it will never be like 'guzzi'` While this may be true for this particular example, it certainly isn't true as a general principle.

Comment: @Strawberry yes, yes. It's true for his application, as he's checking product's brands. So if a product is a Guzzi, can't be also a Citroen :)

Comment: There's a car manufacturer called 'Ssanyong', and another car manufacturer called 'San'. We cannot say that if a productname is like 'Ssanyong' it will never be like 'San'.

Comment: I thought about the need @leveragingR has from his query. A better structure of the DB would have been a `manufacturer` table with its `id` field and his query would have been `products.manufacturer_id = <manufacturer id for Citroen> AND products.manufacturer_id != <manufacturer id for Guzzi>`. The second condition, once verified the first, it's totally useless. I thought about the "concept" of the query, not just the syntax in a totally general situation

Comment: Sorry guys, I just saw your messages. In the database, there were customers who bought both Citroen and Guzzi. Indeed, in my previous trial, I was selecting just who bought Citroen without excluding who also bought Guzzi. This resulted in 24 rows. Differently, adding the condition with NOT EXISTS, I was correctly able to manage that and exclude the Guzzi ones, resulting in 18 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional aggregation to count how many products of each type were purchased...

```
SELECT
  o.customerNumber
FROM
  orders o
INNER JOIN
  orderdetails od
    USING (orderNumber)
INNER JOIN
  products p
    USING (productCode)
WHERE
     p.productName LIKE '%citroen%'
  OR p.productName LIKE '%guzzi%'
GROUP BY
  o.customerNumber
HAVING
      MAX(CASE WHEN p.productName LIKE '%citroen%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
  AND MAX(CASE WHEN p.productName LIKE '%guzzi%'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Longer, but can be faster if each customer has (on average) a ***very*** large number of relevant purchases...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  customer
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT
      o.customerNumber
    FROM
      orders o
    INNER JOIN
      orderdetails od
        USING (orderNumber)
    INNER JOIN
      products p
        USING (productCode)
    WHERE
          o.customerNumber  =   customer.CustomerNumber
      AND p.productName    LIKE '%citroen%'
  )
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
      o.customerNumber
    FROM
      orders o
    INNER JOIN
      orderdetails od
        USING (orderNumber)
    INNER JOIN
      products p
        USING (productCode)
    WHERE
          o.customerNumber  =   customer.CustomerNumber
      AND p.productName    LIKE '%guzzi%'
  )
```